# Weird behaviour with Double Tapping BottomTabNavigator - React Navigation

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I use React Navigation to do my Navigation in my mobile app and I have a structure navigation like this:

```
const AccountStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Account: AccountView,
        ...

    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Account',
        headerMode: 'screen',
        ....
    }
)

const SearchUsersStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        SearchUsers: SearchUsersView,
        UserProfile: UserProfileView,
        FriendsOfUser: FriendsOfUserView
    },
    {
        ...
    }
)

const AccountModalStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        AccountStack: AccountStack,
        SearchUsersStack: SearchUsersStack,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AccountStack',
        headerMode: 'none',
        mode: 'modal',

    }
)

const MainApp = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        MainHome: HomeStack,
        MainPlay: PlayStack,
        MainAccount: AccountModalStack
    },
    {
        ...
    }
)
```

If I'm in the "search User" stack (for example, in SearchUserView) and I click on the "Account" icon in the bottom tab navigator, the stack will dismiss correctly and I will return to my "account" view.

However, if I am in one of the routes of my AccountStack and I click on the "Account" icon in the bottom tab navigator, the stack does not dismiss. So if I'm very far in the account stack, I have to go back with the back arrow.

Why does it work when I'm in the SearchUserStack but not when I'm in my AccountStack ?

I hope to find help!

Thank you !

Viktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override what happens when you tap on a tab, which you can do via the `navigationOptions` of each navigator in the tab bar.

```js
const AccountModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    AccountStack: AccountStack,
    SearchUsersStack: SearchUsersStack,
    // ...
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AccountStack',
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => {
        navigation.navigate({
          routeName: 'AccountStack', // navigates to the initial route
          action: navigation.popToTop(), // go to the top of the stack of that route
        })
      },
      // ...
    },
    // ...
  }
)
```

It's likely that the tab by default attempts to simply navigate to the initial route, without resetting the stack.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much! I finally added the "TabBarOnPress" on the bottomTabNav and I added a global variable that allows me to retrieve the state of the last navigation on the BottomTab so, I can manage the double tap for all my account! You save my day